# Changing Baud Rate not working

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer, mpu6050, gyroscope, baud-rate

I have copied this code from [Github](https://github.com/jarzebski/Arduino-MPU6050/blob/master/MPU6050_gyro_pitch_roll_yaw/MPU6050_gyro_pitch_roll_yaw.ino) :

```
 #include <Wire.h>
 #include <MPU6050.h>

MPU6050 mpu;

// Timers
unsigned long timer = 0;
float timeStep = 0.01;

// Pitch, Roll and Yaw values
float pitch = 0;
float roll = 0;
float yaw = 0;

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    //Serial.begin(9600);

    // Initialize MPU6050
    while(!mpu.begin(MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS, MPU6050_RANGE_2G))
    {
         //Serial.println("Could not find a valid MPU6050 sensor, check 
               wiring!");
     }

     // Calibrate gyroscope. The calibration must be at rest.
     // If you don't want calibrate, comment this line.
    //mpu.calibrateGyro();

     // Set threshold sensivty. Default 3.
     // If you don't want use threshold, comment this line or set 0.
      mpu.setThreshold(1);
   }

   void loop()
      {
       timer = millis();

      // Read normalized values
     Vector norm = mpu.readNormalizeGyro();

     // Calculate Pitch, Roll and Yaw
      pitch = pitch + norm.YAxis * timeStep;
       roll = roll + norm.XAxis * timeStep;
       yaw = yaw + norm.ZAxis * timeStep;

         // Output raw
      //Serial.print(" Pitch = ");
         Serial.print(pitch);  
           Serial.print(":"); 
        //Serial.print(" Roll = ");
     Serial.print(roll);  
        Serial.print(":");  
       //Serial.print(" Yaw = ");
        Serial.println(yaw);

           // Wait to full timeStep period
      delay((timeStep*1000) - (millis() - timer));
     }
```

**Now the question is, whenever I try to change the baud rate Serial Monitor becomes empty.**

*How can this be resolved?*

Some screen-shots :

[image: At 03:38]
[image: At 03:39]

Stuck!!!

Comment: where do you change the baud rate?

Comment: I changed, but nothing happened so I commented that line

Comment: please see there is a line `//Serial.begin(9600);`

Comment: And did you also change the baud rate in the serial monitor?

Comment: Yes, I have added screenshots ...

Answer (score 1):

You are not very much clear but these are the possible reasons for your problem.

1. You are using a while loop in your setup() function in your code. Your code might get stuck in there that's why you are not able to see pitch and roll. Try removing comment from the Serial.begin function over there.
2. After Changing baudrate in your code please make sure you are changing it on your serial monitor as well.

Comment: I have changed the  baud rate both in code & serial monitor. After printing 6/7 values it gets stuck. I have no idea whats going on   :'(

Comment: I also added a `Serial.println("ok")` at the last line of `Setup` that worked.

Comment: can you provide screenshot of your serial monitor.

Comment: I have added screenshots, please see

Comment: last thing that i understand that can make issue is that delay function in the end, try setting some default value in that like 5 or 10 then check if window still stucks

Comment: I tried that too, but didn't working with `115200` baud rate

Comment: maybe it's because of the library

Comment: i think so as i tried your code with mpu part commented and code works well. Try this [library example](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050)

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to move and rotate an object in Unity using Arduino as input . Now I have [this](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Mouse-3D) , rotation is perfect but, position isn't . Maybe you can help me with that.